# how to remove this internal light blue color which appear while hovering?

Tags: html, css

```
 <a src="http://jsfiddle.net/gzhLfthy/"> </a>
```

I'm sharing jsfiddle please take a look over it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gzhLfthy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove background color from a hover

```
#navbar li:hover > a {
 /* background:#5cadff;*/
  color:#fff;
}
```

Please find updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gzhLfthy/1/

Answer (score 2):

It is because of a rule in this selector:

```css
#navbar>ul>li>ul>li
```

Give this in your CSS file:

```css
#navbar>ul>li>ul>li {background: transparent;}
```

It is here in your CSS:

```css
#navbar li:hover > a {
  background:#5cadff;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: i gave but it couldn't work i want the light blue color over full block while hovering not just covering text part,

Comment: You said how to `remove`, isn't it?

Comment: @sony Try `#navbar>ul>li>ul>li:hover {background: #5cadff;}`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this on your css

```
#navbar>ul>li>ul>li:hover
{
  background:#204d86;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to remove it to remove the internal light blue color